# Align Text In Middle next to an Image

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a div with a class of col-md-6 and I'm trying to position text next to the image right in the middle. What code works for that? The only way I've found possible, but not accurate is by messing with the padding.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#wrapper2 h1 {
  text-align: center
}

#wrapper2 p {
  text-align: center;
}

.col-md-6 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="wrapper2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/47/3d/e8/473de83da9ad0e72e340022bb68e9429.jpg>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Men's Line</h1>
        <p>Shop our newest 2017 arrivals</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u5qngm5q/

Comment: Do you actually want the image to take up 50% of the row while the text/description takes up the other half? Or is that simply a mechanism that you were using to align the two?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your own custom column css class and set its display to table-cell. Finally, make vertical-align and text-align properties to middle.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#wrapper2 h1 {
  text-align: center
}

#wrapper2 p {
  text-align: center;
}

.col-md-6 {
  padding: 0;
}
.custom-column{
  display:table-cell;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="wrapper2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="custom-column">
        <img class="img-responsive" src=https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/47/3d/e8/473de83da9ad0e72e340022bb68e9429.jpg>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-column">
          <h1>Men's Line</h1>
          <p>Shop our newest 2017 arrivals</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if I like the skirting of Bootstrap columns to make this work.

Comment: You did not intervene with anything. You just add another class.

Comment: You don't know that for sure. What if the OP wants to use the breakpoints provided by Bootstrap columns? Your answer does not include the Bootstrap column classes and even it had your solution would override them to behave differently.

Comment: What does the OP stand for?

Comment: OP = **O**riginal **P**oster = the person that posted the question.

Comment: You should be asking him and not arguing with me!

Comment: No, not arguing. I'm pointing out a very real and potential flaw, which is, ignoring the responsive features of Bootstrap columns. Pointing it out is not arguing. Neither is pointing out an incorrect observation.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to the `.row` class will have this effect. Also adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` will make the code responsive. Then add `flex-grow:1;` to your text container for centering the text in mobile view [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5qngm5q/7/)

### HTML

```
<div class="row flex-center">
  <div class="col-md-6 text-container">
   <h1>Men's Line</h1>
   <p>Shop our newest 2017 arrivals</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.flex-center {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
} 

.text-container {
  flex-grow : 1;
}
```